# SQL Server: select random rows with distinct id from table where id is not distinct

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a simple table named `Tickets` with the following columns:

```
ticketId, userId
```

where `ticketId` is the primary key, `UserId` is not unique.

A user can therefore have several tickets, each with unique `ticketId`'s.

I'm struggling to find a solution on my problem which is that I need to select 5 random tickets by 5 unique userId's.

I know how to select the random tickets by using the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Tickets
ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(*) * RAND())
```

Which returns something like:

```
Ticket id:         UserId:
--------------------------
10                 1
25                 1
31                 2
42                 2
56                 3
```

My question is: what do I need to add to the query for it to select the random rows between distinct userId's so that it does not return more than one unique ticket for a user

Mind I need the most performance correct solution, since the table could potentially be filled with millions of rows in the long run.

Thanks in advance,
Christian

**Edit:** 
The more tickets a user has, the higher the chances of selection. However it should still be randomly selected and not just select the user with the highest amount of tickets. Just like in a lottery.

In other words it should select 5 random rows between all rows, but ensure that the 5 rows have a unique userId.

Comment: Recommend checking out this article if you are concerned about performance and table size: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If a user has many tickets, should they be more likely to be returned?

Comment: @David. Hey David, think of it like a lottery. If a user has two tickets and another one has 1, the first should, at least in theory, have a higher chance of getting selected.

Comment: there are a couple of approaches you could take.  One is to select the user randomly from a list of distinct users, but then it isn't weighted by the number of tickets the user has.  Another way is to do what you're doing, remove any duplicates selected, exclude selected userIDs from your next pull, and try again.  You might need to try multiple times, though, before you get a distinct list of userIDs.

Comment: @Beth. Thank you for your thoughts. I was going to use your last idea as a last resort if nothing else worked.

Comment: I interpret the question as meaning that "tickets should be selected randomly, but each unique user should only win once per run of the query" (i.e. holding two tickets doubles their chance of winning, but having won on one ticket, they should not win again on a second ticket).

Comment: @Steve. Correct! However only 5 winners in total Should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following I think.

Please note this code is untested, so please excuse any small syntax errors.

```
WITH randomised_tickets AS
(
    SELECT 
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) AS random_order

    FROM Tickets
)

,ordered_winning_tickets AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY random_order ASC) AS user_win_order

    FROM randomised_tickets
)

SELECT TOP 5
    *

FROM 
    ordered_winning_tickets

WHERE
    user_win_order = 1 --eliminate 2nd wins from the list

ORDER BY
    random_order
```

Comment: Hey Steve, I just tried running your query but in a test table with 1 million records it always just return the 5 same tickets.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND() ASC) AS random_order` This won't work.  The `RAND()` function executes once per query.  You need a function that executes once per row, like `NEWID()` does.

Comment: @BaconBits, agreed!

Comment: @Klatzen, I've adjusted the query to fix. Also note my comment on EdmCoff's answer.

Comment: Oh i didn't notice that it didn't take the amount of tickets into account. I will test your updated answer tomorrow. If it works I will select it as the right answer since its solves my whole problem statement. :-)

Comment: @Steve. Just tested it this morning and it seems to do the trick!

Comment: @Klatzen, just one more thing. As BaconBits pointed out in another comment, something like `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16)` could be a better solution in this case, as `NEWID()` is not designed specifically for randomness - it may do the job on a one-off basis, but if you were running this query fairly regularly with the same potential winners each time, then you'd need to think about the importance of being fair to ticket-holders and avoiding embarrassment if some winners appear far too frequently using the `NEWID()` function.

Comment: @Steve. That's a valid consideration and definitely something I have to take into account. I did however test your query with the crypt_gen_random instead of NewId() and it took a huge performance hit, like doubled the execution time on a table with 1 mil. rows. However since this query is only supposed to be executed once a month i guess it wont have such a huge impact.

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this .... NEWID()

```
Select UserId
from 
(
    SELECT TOP 5 UserId 
    FROM Tickets
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)k 
CROSS APPLY 
( 
      select top 1 TicketId 
      from Tickets T WHERE T.UserId = k.UserId
      ORDER BY NEWID()
)u
```

Comment: I don't think this meets the (newly added) requirement in the comments that the probability of a user with 1000 tickets being selected should be higher than the probability of a user with 1 ticket being selected. Do you no longer care about that?

Comment: Edit: just tested it on a larger dataset. It is not working as it returns all rows instead of just the top 5

Comment: @EdmCoff I just found out that the above did not work as expected on a larger dataset. Yes I would like users with more tickets to have a higher chance of getting selected.

However it should not be something like the user with the highest amount of tickets will always get selected first. It must still be random, like in a lottery :-)

Comment: I have updated the solution, can you please check. If not working can you please provide some sample data and expected data.

Comment: I think the confusion is that this solution needs a "top 5" at the top and another "ORDER BY NEWID()" (on the main query). But that's still not going to make it select a user with 1000 tickets more frequently than it selects a user with 1 ticket.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this solution doesn't properly weight the users by number of tickets (so a user with 1000 tickets incorrectly has same change of winning as user with 1 ticket). This was particularly dumb of me since I pointed out this problem on other answers.

Given that Steve now has his solution working, I think that is the better answer.

**Original answer:**

I think something like the following works:

```
SELECT top 5 ticketid, userid
FROM
   (
     SELECT ticketid, userid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY NEWID()) as nid
     FROM tickets
    ) a
WHERE  nid = 1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Here's an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20e6ce/54/0) to play around with it.

Credit where credit is due: I based this on [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9129668/steve)'s solution which I don't think works correctly as written.

Comment: Tested it on 1 million rows and a table with just 4 where only two of them have unique userId's. It seems to work as I want it to. Thank you very much! Selecting this as working answer :-)

Comment: If this is for anything important or if the prizes are significant, I wouldn't rely on `NEWID()`.  I would use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16)` (or some other length) which generates the number from the Crypto API.

Comment: @Bacon Bits. Thank you for the heads-up I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @EdmCoff, Thanks for the mention! As I say, I didn't test my code. The only observation I'd make about your approach is that it does not preserve the weighting of multiple tickets, because it eliminates them (choosing the victim tickets randomly) before the winners are selected (in the final `ORDER BY NEWID()`). My code picks the order of winning tickets first, and only removes those which would have represented the 2nd wins in the final output (the winning order being maintained by carrying through from the first round when all tickets were still present in the set).

Comment: @steve Thanks. I've edited the post to warn people about that. I guess I got  a little too carried away with simplifying my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, using ignore_dup_key on a temp table to eliminate duplciates for a user:

```
 drop table if exists #WinningTickets
 create table #WinningTickets(PickId int identity primary key, TicketId int, UserId int)
 create unique index ix_unique_user on #WinningTickets(UserId) with (ignore_dup_key=on)

 while ( select count(*) from #WinningTickets ) < 5
 begin
   insert into #WinningTickets
   select top 10 TicketId, UserId
   from Tickets
   order by newid()
 end

 select top 5 * 
 from #WinningTickets
 order by PickId
```

Comment: Hey David. I tried inputting your query but it cant find "if exists"? Might it be something with the version of SQL server i'm running?

Comment: Yep.  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS was introduced in SQL 2016.  If this is a stored procedure, just omit the DROP TABLE.  The temp table will be dropped automatically at the end of the procedure.

Comment: Ahh okay. Just for the sake og learning, isnt using while bad practice in terms of performance?

Comment: Performance is always a matter of "good enough", and this problem is going to require a multi-pass approach of some kind.